# SQL Query to get countries

Tags: sql

I have a table with the fileds

Table Name:
**CountriesInfo**

```
country | continent
--------|----------
India   | Asia
China   | Asia
Ireland | Europe
England | Europe
```

1. User will select a country
2. System should display all other countries which are in the same continent of the selected country 
   I want to use JOINS only (not subqueries).  Is there a way to get?

Comment: What have you tried? Which database system are you using (MySQL, SQL SERVER etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

You can join with the same table and get result:

```
select C.country
from   CountriesInfo C 
join
    (select *
     from  CountriesInfo
     where country='India')a
on C.continent=a.continent
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff01c7/1)

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the SQL Fiddle.  I never know about this.

Comment: This answer is not correct as it returns the chosen country in the result set and also uses a sub select. When the OP hands in his homework, he will be marked down! ;-)     I also hadn't seen SQL Fiddle before - thanks for that, it's cool!

Answer (score 1):

> System should display all other countries which are in the same
>   continent of the selected country I want to use JOINS only (not
>   subqueries). Is there a way to get?

Yes this is the way to get it. This will work for both SQL Server & MySQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C2.country 
FROM CountriesInfo C1 
JOIN CountriesInfo C2 ON C1.continent=C2.continent 
WHERE C1.country='INDIA'
```

[See the demo for MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aa9e/1)
[See the demo for SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3075/1)

Answer (score 0):

use this query to self join the table:

```
SELECT T2.Country
FROM CountriesInfo T1
JOIN CountriesInfo T2 ON T1.Continent = T2.Continent
WHERE T1.Country = 'Ireland'
```

of course you can pass parameter to the where clause (instead of "Ireland").
this query is self join itself, giving you the list of the countries that are in the same continent as the selected one.

Comment: This doesn't work. It will return Ireland twice. You need to change it to be select `T2.*` or better still, `T2.country`

Comment: you're right Dommer, fixed. thanks for the attention fixed :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.country 
from countriesInfo R, countriesInfo S
where r.country = 'india'
and s.continent = r.continent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ci2.country FROM CountriesInfo ci1
JOIN CountriesInfo ci2 ON ci1.continent=ci2.continent
WHERE ci1.country=<SELECTED_COUNTRY>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit like homework to me! One way to do it is like this:

```
DECLARE @chosenCountry VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @chosenCountry = 'India' -- Set it however you want here...

SELECT ciSameContinent.country FROM CountriesInfo ci
INNER JOIN CountriesInfo ciSameContinent ON ci.continent = ciSameContinent.continent
WHERE ci.country = @chosenCountry
AND ciSameContinent.country <> @chosenCountry -- Forgot this bit which is needed to exclude the chosen country as per the question
```

This satisfies the requirement as it returns the OTHER countries from the same continent (and excludes the chosen country) and does NOT use a sub select.